# How do I create a required "BelongsTo" association using Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Using [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com), I've created two models: `User` and `Login`.

Users can have more than one Login, but a login must have exactly one user.

How do I specify in the login model that a user must exist before a save can occur?

**Current Code**

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {});
var Login = sequelize.define('Login', {});
Login.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
```

This setup would still allow a login to save before a user has been specified.  For instance `Login.build().save();` would execute without any validation error.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2837

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer lies in the foreignKey attribute, which actually takes in a full blown [column object](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#define).

Specifically, instead if `'userId'` it should be:

```
Login.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: {
    field: 'userId',
    allowNull: false
  },
  onDelete: 'cascade'
});
```

Notice that onDelete has to be updated as well, because the default value for onDelete is `SET NULL` which may generate errors at the database level due to the rule conflict.

*Thank you to the friendly folks in #sequelizejs on Freenode!*

Comment: You must put the constraint on both models for this to work.